# FullCalendar agenda view events don't show when allDaySlot=true

Tags: fullcalendar

Sorry if this has been asked previously, but I couldn't find the answer. In the agenda views, if I have allDaySlot = true, then only the All Day section is displayed and no time-specific events (or even the time panel) are displayed. If I have allDaySlot = false, then the time specific events display, but not the All Day Events. Here is my calendar setup:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate:  "2016-12-05",
    allDaySlot: true,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek', 
    events: [{ id:1,
           start: "2016-12-06T10:00:00",
           end:"2016-12-06T18:00:00",
           title: 'test timed event',
           allDay: false }, 
        { id:2,
          start: "2016-12-07",
          title: 'All Day Event',
          allDay: true }
    ]

});
```

Here is the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75zKp.png)

As with most things, I'm sure I'm missing something quite simple. Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else. The code you mentioned works correctly. Please check - https://jsfiddle.net/vacctg4f/. Can you share the whole page code or check if there is no exceptions in browser console?

Comment: Thanks @KrzysztofKaźmierczak, I thought that code was correct. Do you think an old version of jQuery would cause this behavior? We are on an old version of the jQuery library (1.8.2)

Comment: And no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Krysztof, my code functions correctly. I stripped down the page containing my code (removing a master page, etc) and the code functions correctly in my app. So, I'm off to hunt for the conflicting code.

EDIT (for someone else having this problem): My page references a .NET master page and the calendar resides inside a content tag. I believe this is causing a conflict on the "fc-time-grid-container" element of FullCalendar. This element has an inline style applied to it for Overflow-x and Overflow-y. Removing those settings renders the calendar correctly. For now, I'll remove them via javaScript code after the calendar renders until I can find a better solution.